# Are all realistic quantum-mechanical expectation values Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

I was asked if it might be possible use entanglement to travel faster than light. Trying to formulate this in a more orthodox way, I ended up with this question:

*Is there a proof that the expectation values for quantum mechanical many particle states are Lorentz-invariant for all realistic Observables and Hamiltonians?*

**Edit:** I should explain the motivation behind this strange question. We've been irritated after watching the Quantum Theory documentation by Brian Greene. The movie does not explicitly state that quantum entanglement might make it possible to travel faster than light one day, but it suggests this possibility. To my experience, everyone except Brian Green and a few weirdos is very sure that due to quantum mechanics no macroscopic thing will ever travel faster than light. So, there should be a clear and strict proof for that. If all expectation values were Lorentz-invariant, I would consider this a quiet convincing argument.

Comment: It follows from linearity of expectation that if the observable is covariant/invariant, then so is its expectation value. What is the question about that and what has this to do with "travelling faster than light"?

Comment: Do you mean ordinary (non-relativistic) QM or relativistic QM?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the more realistic one: let's say relativisic QM

Comment: @ACuriousMind Starting from co-/invariant operators and arguing with the linearity of the expectation value sounds good. However, I'm not sure if we always can do without the time-ordering operators.

Comment: What are realistic observables ?

Comment: @DanielC I mean observables that we cannot blame if Lorentz-invariance is broken. Let's say observables that are themselves Lorentz-invariant. According to our picture (Schrödinger/Heisenberg/...) it might be necessary to also consider time ordering.

Answer (score 1):

This is an experimentalist's answer:

From the [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) to *every observable there corresponds an operator*, and also  *For a system described by a given wavefunction, the expectation value of any property q can be found by performing the expectation value integral with respect to that wavefunction*.

You are asking about traveling faster than light. That is the observable and there should be an operator within the quantum mechanical frame whose expectation value will give a velocity faster than light ( otherwise how would one know it if not by a measurement?).

So, in my opinion since operators in a consistent quantum mechanical definition have to be Lorenz invariant, an operator giving a measurement faster than light cannot be  Lorenz invariant, and consistent with the closed system of a relativistic quantum mechanical model.

Comment: I'm convinced for a one-particle-system. But still brooding whether the symmetrization or antisymmetrization of a many-particle wave function might disturb the Lorentz-invariance.

Comment: One would have to work with the density matrix for a many body system, and it seems to me that since the wavefunctions are relativistically invariant by construction any system would also have to be but as I said I am an experimentalist . found this and the abstract seems to agree https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0307107.pdf